# Registros Diferentes

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
MATRICULA_A <-c(123,234,345,456)
dados_1 <- data.frame(MATRICULA_A)

MATRICULA_A <-c(345,456,111,222,333,444)
dados_2 <- data.frame(MATRICULA_A)
```

Necessito extrair somente as informações da tabela `dados_1` que são diferentes da `dados_2`. Neste exemplo, quero que apareça, como resultado, somente as matrículas 123 e 234 (`dados_1`). Tentei através do `anti_join` e não deu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei como você utilizou a função `anti_join`, mas ela funcionou aqui:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(dados_1,dados_2,by='MATRICULA_A') # 'MATRICULA_A' é a variável em comum

  MATRICULA_A
1         123
2         234
```

Answer (score 2):

Em R base pode fazer isso de várias maneiras.

Com `setdiff`:

```
setdiff(dados_1$MATRICULA_A, dados_2$MATRICULA_A)
#[1] 123 234
```

Com `%in%` é mais flexível, tanto pode obter um vetor como um objeto de classe `"data.frame"`, tal como o original `df1`:

```
i <- !dados_1$MATRICULA_A %in% dados_2$MATRICULA_A

dados_1[i, ]
#[1] 123 234

dados_1[i, , drop = FALSE]
#  MATRICULA_A
#1         123
#2         234
```