# Como fazer a diferença entre dois data.frames no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Criei dois `data.frames`: o primeiro `data.frame` que vem de uma base original e o segundo `data.frame` que tem origem no primeiro, mas com aplicação de um filtro.

Exemplo:

```
print(DADOS)

    CODE  A  B  C  D  E  COUNT
     001  0  0  1  1  0  2
     002  1  1  1  1  1  5
     003  0  1  0  1  0  2
     004  1  1  1  0  0  3

DADOS_FILTRADOS = DADOS %>%
filter(COUNT > 3)

print(DADOS_FILTRADOS)

    CODE  A  B  C  D  E  COUNT
     002  1  1  1  1  1  5
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é encontrar a diferença entre esses dois data.frames, Ou seja, fazer a tabela `DADOS` menos a tabela `DADOS_FILTRADOS`. O que poderia ser feito?

Comment: Veja se esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/345482/registros-diferentes/345484#345484) pode ajudar.

Comment: @user108927 Vou verificar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), o pacote [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) apresenta a solução do `anti_join()`.

Primeiro, vamos reproduzir os dados,

```
txt1 <- "CODE  A  B  C  D  E  COUNT
001  0  0  1  1  0  2
002  1  1  1  1  1  5
003  0  1  0  1  0  2
004  1  1  1  0  0  3"

txt2 <- "CODE  A  B  C  D  E  COUNT
002  1  1  1  1  1  5"

dados <- read.table(text = txt1, header = TRUE)
dados_filtrados <- read.table(text = txt2, header = TRUE)
```

Agora podemos verificar a diferença. A função `anti_join()` tem três argumentos principais

1. `x`: a tabela em que será retornada sem os registros que batem
2. `y`: a tabela em que será usada para eliminar os registros da primeira
3. `by`: o nome dos campos que devem ser usados como chave

O código então fica assim:

```
library(dplyr)

anti_join(dados, dados_filtrados, "CODE")
#   CODE A B C D E COUNT
# 1    1 0 0 1 1 0     2
# 2    3 0 1 0 1 0     2
# 3    4 1 1 1 0 0     3
```

[Esse repositório](https://github.com/gadenbuie/tidyexplain) tem vários `gif`s para ajuda a entender algumas a idéias tem manipulação/união de tabelas. Em específico o `anti_join()` está [aqui](https://github.com/gadenbuie/tidyexplain#anti-join).

Comment: Tomás vou testar, parece ser bem simples. Eu imaginei que "operações" entre data.frames fossem mais complexas.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no link que incluí, ele ajuda a ver a simplicidade dessas operações.

Comment: Vou olhar sim @Tomás Barcellos =)